# Hide accounts with < n reputation

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

My profile's page's [public-facing Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/211113/james-donnelly?tab=topactivity) shows that I have 17 Stack Exchange accounts. 7 of these have the default 101 Reputation gained from linking my account, and only 2 of them have more than 300 reputation.

[image: Example]

Now I could manually edit my profile to hide the 7 somewhat-irrelevant Stack Exchange sites, and perhaps also hide the 8 other sites which I have below 300 reputation on, but to me this seems a bit long-winded and I'm the type of person who would forget to re-enable certain sites if I were to become more active on them.

I think what'd be great is a filter in the *Hide Communities* settings page which allows me to dynamically specify that I want to hide all communities from my profile where I have below *n* reputation. This way I'd never have to worry about re-enabling certain sites, and if I log in to a new site without ever participating it wouldn't automatically add it to my accounts list.

Comment: Less than 200 don't show in flar. But I like this idea.